# How to initialize string in struct without using strcpy function?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, strcpy

Is there any manual way to initialize the string in struct ? I used to initialize string in struct using strcpy function such as:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[20];
    int age;
} employee;


int main()
{
    employee x;
    x.age=25;

    strcpy(x.name,"sam");
    printf("employee age is %d \n",x.age);
    printf("employee name is %s",x.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `employee x = { .age = 25, .name = "sam"};`

Comment: Why? Since your question seems absurd, explain why.

Comment: to copy into a fixed-size array, you should always use strncpy(), or strncpy_s, if available.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Disagree with "to copy into a fixed-size array, you should always use strncpy(),  ..."

Comment: You can.  But don't come posting questions here about buffer overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking this

```
strcpy(x.name,"sam");
```

is not an initialization.

if to speak about the initialization then you can do it the following way

```
employee x = { .name = "sam", .age = 25 };
```

or

```
employee x = { .name = { "sam" }, .age = 25 };
```

This is equivalent to the following initialization

```
employee x = { 0, "sam", 25 };
```

or

```
employee x = { 0, { "sam" }, 25 };
```

Or you even can use a compound literal of the type `employee` to initialize the object `x` though that is not efficient.

Otherwise if is not an initialization but an assignment of the data member of the structure then indeed you have to use at least `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

Comment: Good answer aside from "compound literal ... though that is not efficient.".  Certainly a good compiler will optimize that as well as other approaches.

Comment: Assignment can use a _compound literal_ without `strcpy()` and friends.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your own version of `strcpy`:

```
void mycopy(char *dest, const char *source, size_t ndest)
{
    assert(ndest != 0);
    while (--ndest > 0 && (*dest++ = *source++))
        ;
}
```

You're not using `strcpy` anymore. Plus it is safer.

Comment: You should have clearly marked this as "sarcastic". I assume it is sarcastic. If not, then your employer should be frightened.

Comment: @gnasher729 why should my boss my scared? This version is safer

Comment: I have not seen so badly written simple function for years

Comment: @PeterJ Where are the problems?

Comment: @PeterJ, that's the user's fault for passing bad input. I could add an assertion, but i didnt want to distract

Comment: going to bed enough for today

Comment: There need to be parentheses around the assignment since `&&` has higher precedence than `=`.

Comment: Your function is as safe as strncpy,  If the string is longer than max, the destination is not null terminated.  strncpy_s was added to the library so we shouldn't have to squint at code like this.

Comment: Thinking about it, your function is slower than strncpy() for the exact same functionality, and dangers.

Comment: Corner case weakness: `mycopy(dest, source, 0)` leads to buffer overrun. `strncpy()` does not have that problem.

Answer (score -1):

max - including trailing zero

```
char *mystrncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t max)
{
    char *tmp = dest;

    if (max)
    {
        while (--max && *src)
        {
            *dest++ = *src++;
        }

    *dest++ = '\0';
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: `*dest++ = '\0';` belongs inside `if(max)`